# Call methods in WPF window from main thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

**Use case**
I'm developing a small application in C# that is called by another application to retrieve data from the Internet. It runs as a process on its own, but almost all of the interaction with it, is managed by the calling application. Therefor it does not have a GUI. However I'd like to add a progress bar using WPF that is shown during certain data retrievals that could take up to a minute. It's fairly easy to make an estimate of how much work is done and how much is left and therefor I find a progress bar suitable.

**Research done**
I have a fair understanding of threading after reading large parts of Albahari's pdf on threading (http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf). I have also read through a lot of posts on SO and MSDN in this matter. Most posts suggest the use of a background worker for the time consuming data retrieval while keeping the GUI in the main thread and therefor suggest solutions using a background worker. That feels awkward in this scenario though, where the main task is data retrieval and not GUI interaction.

I've spend a bunch of hours trying to make sense of different tutorials and forum posts while trying to conform them to my problem, but I have not succeeded and now I'm pretty much back to square one. Basically I'd like to end up with the following two classes outlined below:

**ProgressBarWindow**

```
public partial class ProgressBarWindow : Window
{
    public ProgressBarWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setValue(int value) 
    {
        // This function should be available from the main thread
    }
}
```

**Querier**

```
Public class Querier
{



    public List<Item> getItems()
    {
        // call ProgressBarWindow.setValue(0);
        ...
        // call ProgressBarWindow.setValue(100);
        // call ProgressBarWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

It's my understanding that UI must run under single threads and therefor my `ProgressBarWindow` object could not be instantiated in a new thread while at the same time be available to the main thread (kind of).

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke appears to be my savior here but so far I haven't been able to figure out what should go into the `Querier` class and what to go in the `ProgressBarWindow` class. How can I make the two threads interact with the same instance of ProgressBarWindow?

Please ask if you need more details and I will try to clarify.

Comment: Please avoid the `setXXX()` and `getXXX()` syntax. it looks so much java-like that I'm about to throw up. Instead of that, use C#-like code and create proper Properties.

Comment: Point taken! I usually try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Progress` class to update the UI with the current progress of a long running operation.

First create an instance of `Progress` in your UI:

```
Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(currentProgress =>
{
    progressBar.Value = currentProgress;
    //todo do other stuff
});
```

Then pass it to the long running process:

```
public List<Item> getItems(IProgress<int> progress)
{
    progress.Report(0);
    //todo do something
    progress.Report(100);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I'm trying to briefly work it out in my head. I don't see where the new thread should be created. Would that be implemented in the "long running process"?

Comment: @Anders I was under the impression that you didn't have a problem running some code in a background thread, but rather with getting the progress back to the UI thread.  You can simply use `Task.Run(() => whatever.GetItems(progress))` to run `getItems` in a non-UI thread, although there are many other techniques that will all work just as well.  That's a main advantage of using `Progress`, it doesn't care how you end up running code in another thread.

Comment: I would like it the other way around. The Progress bar should run in a background thread which leaves me with something like: `Task.Run(() => new ProgressBarDialog().showDialog()`. But I guess it would be possible to trade delegates inside the anonymous function as well to make it possible to transmit status changes through them?

Comment: @Anders That would be creating multiple UI thread.  Don't do that.  Just don't.  Have one UI thread that manages all of your UI components.  If you have long running non-UI work to do then do that in a non-UI thread.  You'll create way, way, more headaches for yourself trying to create a second UI thread to manage progress just so that you can do non-UI work in the UI thread.

Comment: I actually don't have another UI. Or at least not what I call UI. So the only time the program "interacts" with the user is the ProgressBarWindow. No other Winforms or WPF are implemented.

Comment: @Anders A new progress bar window sounds very much like a UI to me.  It's a dialog box that you're showing to the user.  That's a UI.  That shouldn't be managed from another thread, it should use a singular UI thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43290/discussion-between-anders-and-servy)

Comment: Okey! Now I've done some testing. First of all I had to put a reference to progressBar in a static member to make it available to the lambda expression for the Progress constructor. Was that correct so far? When running the code I get InvalidOperationException because I'm trying to access ProgressBar from the background thread and ProgressBar belongs to the UI thread. I used the following code to call GetItems: `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ThreadTest.GetItems(w.progress));`

Comment: @Anders The progress bar shouldn't be static, no.  You should be creating the progress bar, as well as the `Progress` instance in the UI thread, just before starting the long running process in a non-UI thread.  Both can generally just be local variables.  If you're getting an exception then it means you're not creating the `Progress` instance from the UI thread, you're creating it from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Now I see. Thank you for your help. I think I got it working now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function which i generally use:

```
    public static void Invoke(this UIElement element,Action action)
    {
        element.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, null);
    }
```

And to use it, simply call:

```
this.Invoke(() => ProgressBarWindow.SetValue(0));
```

So, in the getItems() function, you would have something along the lines of:

```
public List<Item> getItems()
{
    ProgressBarWindow wnd;
    MainWindow.Invoke(() => wnd = new ProgressBarWindow())
    MainWindow.Invoke(() => wnd.SetValue(0))
    ...
    MainWindow.Invoke(() => wnd.SetValue(100))
    MainWindow.Invoke(() => wnd.Close())
}
```

Make sure you always have a way to get to the main window is anything (the one running from either App.xml, or App.Run(...). You can then issue any GUI actions through it (even if you have to create a new Loader window for example, as long as it's done within the main thread)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not sure however what to do with the first formal parameter in the Invoke method. Your example does not state what to send as the actual paramater and Visual Studio complains about the number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> App.xaml

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup_1(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew<List<int>>(() => Querier.GetItems());
    }
}
```

> ProgressBarWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ProgressWindow : Window
{
    public ProgressWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Querier.Start +=()=> Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Querier.Stop += () => Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Querier.ReportProgress +=OnReportProgress;
    }

    public void OnReportProgress(int value)
    {
        txtBox.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

> ProgressBarWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBox"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

> Querier

```
public class Querier
{
    public static event Action Start;

    public static event Action Stop;

    public static event Action<int> ReportProgress;

    public static List<int> GetItems()
    {
        if (Start != null)
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Start,null);

        for (int index = 0; index <= 10; index++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            if (ReportProgress != null)
                App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ReportProgress, index*10);
        }


        if (Stop != null)
            App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Stop, null);

        return Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();

    }

}
```

I am just trying to give an idea hope this will help.

Comment: My project isn't really a WPF project so I'm missing an app.xaml. I've just included a WPF window. Because of this I have a Main method as entry point. This appear to leave me without the possibility to call `App.Current....` or equal.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I currently have a class called `ThreadTest` with a main along with the [STAThread] attribute declared. Visual studio does not recognize `Current` on `ThreadTest`

Comment: is it Console App or Window App?

Comment: It's a console app I'm testing this in. Would that matter so I have to change to Windows app?